# How to make marquee flutter image widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Is that possible to marquee image in a flutter ?
I need to move an image from left to right continually

Comment: take a look at this package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/carousel_pro

Comment: There is no gif so, i  don't understand

Comment: clone the repo and run the sample :) , then you can check the source code if you want to know how it works

Answer (score 2):

Check my gist [autoscroll_text.dart](https://gist.github.com/putraxor/d2949faed074252d160a8a0d47f393e5)

Usage:

```dart
AutoScrollText(
                items: [
                  Text('Hello world '),
                  Text('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet')
                ],
              )
```